# How to increase the execution speed of webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

Actually, I wrote webpack for my website which was using the reactjs. In that I have lot of images and scss files so, that it is taking more amount of time to create bundle.js file upto that the website was in loading state. So, how I can increase the execution speed.

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

let config = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./app/js/index.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "./build.js",
    //publicPath: "/"
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "js": path.resolve(__dirname, "app/js"),
      "css": path.resolve(__dirname, "app/css")
    },
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, loader: "babel-loader"},
      {
       test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
       loader: 'url-loader'
     },
      {test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(["css-loader", "sass-loader"])},
      {test: /\.(jpg|gif|png)$/, loader: "file-loader", options: {name: "./images/[name].[ext]"}},
    ]
  },

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./app/index.html"
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        sassLoader: {
          includePaths: ["app/css"]
        }
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: "style.css",
      allChunks: true
    })
  ]
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        "NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  );
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: post the webpack config and the commands that you are using for development and for creating production builds

Comment: which webpack version are u using ? Post your webpack.config.js file too - it will help us help you.

Comment: @gillyb I attached my code

Answer (score 1):

Besides tweaking your configuration, you could use `webpack --watch` to have webpack watch your source files and recompile whenever you change something. The first compilation will still be a full one, but after that only the necessary parts will be recompiled each time, which can cut down compilation time from 30 seconds to 1 or 2 seconds.

Even better is to set up webpack's [devserver](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) with hot reloading, which also watches and incrementally compiles, but in addition will update your app in the browser, so you won't need to reload the page and lose react state. It can be a bit finicky to set up, but it's well worth the trouble.

Comment: `--watch` should work for any webpack configuration. For an example of how to set up hot reloading, you could check out Dan Abramov's post at https://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/getstarted/